# Как правильно объявить переменные, чтобы при вводе значений в инпут, значения сохранялись в переменную

Tags: php

Есть форма

```
<form role="form" id="form">
    <input id="log_2" type="text" name="test1" value="<?php $a; ?> "/>
    <input type="text" name="test2" value="<?php $b;?>" />
    <button type="submit">
        <a href="/2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-<?php echo $a;?> -<?php echo $b;?>">Подобрать
    </button>
</form>
```

Как правильно объявить переменные, чтобы при вводе значений в инпут, значения сохранялись в переменную, а потом выводились в ссылке?

Answer (score 1):

Схема примерно такая.
1. Показываем пустую форму пользователю

```
<form role="form" id="form" action="/2-catalog" method="get">
    <input id="min-price" type="text" name="min-price" value="" />
    <input id="max-price" type="text" name="max-price" value="" />
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

action - адрес, по которому находится обработчик формы

2. Пользователь нажимает кнопку
3. Получаем введенные данные после отправки формы

$a = $_GET['min-price'];
$b = $_GET['max-price'];
//делаем что-то с полученными данными

P.S. Немного для разъяснения. Php код работает на сервере, после того как мы отправили страничку в браузер пользователю, php кода там уже нет. Затем пользователь ввел данные, нажал кнопку и мы получили на сервере введенные данные.

Comment: всем спасибо конечно, но у меня в адресной строке пишет  /2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-<?php%20echo%20$_GET[%27test1%27];%20?>-<?php%20echo%20$_GET[%27test2%27];?> а хотелось бы/2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-100-200

Comment: Если замените на приведенный код, то при отправке формы будет /2-catalog?min-price=100&max-price=200

Comment: Вы мешаете в кучу серверный и клиентский код, поэтому получается не то, что ожидали.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил - `method="get"`. Как-то так.

```html
<form role="form" id="form" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="test1" value="">
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="">
  <button type="submit">
            <a href="/2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-<?php echo $_GET['test1']; ?>-<?php echo $_GET['test2'];?>">Подобрать
        </button>
</form>
```

> **P.S.** Значение атрибута `method` не зависит от регистра. Различают два
>   метода — `get` и `post`.
>
> **get** Этот метод является одним из самых распространенных и предназначен
>   для получения требуемой информации и передачи данных в адресной
>   строке. Пары «имя=значение» присоединяются в этом случае к адресу
>   после вопросительного знака и разделяются между собой амперсандом
>   (символ &). Удобство использования метода get заключается в том, что
>   адрес со всеми параметрами можно использовать неоднократно, сохранив
>   его, например, в закладки браузера, а также менять значения параметров
>   прямо в адресной строке.
>
> **post** Метод post посылает на сервер данные в
>   запросе браузера. Это позволяет отправлять большее количество данных,
>   чем доступно методу get, поскольку у него установлено ограничение в 4
>   Кб. Большие объемы данных используются в форумах, почтовых службах,
>   заполнении базы данных, при пересылке файлов и др.

Comment: всем спасибо конечно, но у меня в адресной строке пишет  /2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-<?php%20echo%20$_GET[%27test1%27];%20?>-<?php%20echo%20$_GET[%27test2%27];?> а хотелось бы/2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-100-200

Comment: @Kir, тогда попробуйте через JS. Изъять значение из поля в `input`, тогда в JS атрибуту `href` дать нужную вам ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Их с помощью php обьявлять не надо. Тебе с начала надо указать метод в форме Post или Get .в форме надо указать, например: name="value1", и тогда ,чтобы ты мог получить ето значение, пишеш  $_GET['value1'] или Post.

```
<form role="form" id="form" method="get">
```

Comment: всем спасибо конечно, но у меня в адресной строке пишет  /2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-<?php%20echo%20$_GET[%27test1%27];%20?>-<?php%20echo%20$_GET[%27test2%27];?> а хотелось бы/2-catalog?q=Цена-₴-100-200